# add-migration -ConfigurationTypeName type

Tags: entity-framework, c#-4.0, database-migration

hey guys I'm trying to add a data base migration to my project with this cmd

```
 Add-Migration base -ConfigurationTypeName thermilogConfiguration -ConnectionStringName Default
```

but an error occured saying :

> can't find ConfigurationTypeName parameter

any help please

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correctly, the value for -configurationtypename ('thermilogConfiguration' here) should be the name of class like 'Configuration' as below:

```
internal sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<ConsoleApplication4.MyContext> {

   protected override void Seed(ConsoleApplication4.MyContext context) {

   }
}
```

Comment: Yes it is the case actually !! it's just weird why the configurationtypename  parameter can't be found ! :/

Comment: @Mbarka how about adding namespace prefix to the type name? Just guess. Good luck!